# htaccess - how to remove 'index' from url

Tags: apache2, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}
Options All -Indexes

RewriteRule ^index$ ./user/index.php [L,NC]
```

Above is .htaccess code. It shows websitename.com/index when I access home page of website. I want to make it so it only displays websitename.com when I access home page of website.

How can I do it using .htaccess or can it be done only from hosting server settings? Please let me know what settings are required to get desired result.

Comment: @Ziazis, if I do what you have suggested above, then page is not loading at all...

Comment: You should ask this in StackOverflow.

Comment: @luchonacho, I have asked it on StackOverflow also but no luck yet...

Comment: @KAhir please don't cross post.

Comment: @Zacharee1, Sorry but I don't get your comment "please don't cross post" so I can take care of it now or in future.

Comment: @KAhir don't post on multiple StackExchange sites at once

Comment: @Zacharee1, ok I will keep this in mind... ty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally below code works for me.

```
RewriteRule ^$ ./user/index.php [L,NC]
```